# How do I split a line but maintain the rest of the lines in bash?

Tags: bash

I have this:

```
2018-08-18 1 2 0.335106 0.335106
2018-08-19 1 0.335106
2018-08-20 1 0.335106
```

I want this:

```
2018-08-18 1 0.335106 
2018-08-18 2 0.335106
2018-08-19 1 0.335106
2018-08-20 1 0.335106
```

And at the end, I need to get rid of the 1's and 2 too.

So far, I've only been able to get rid of the 1's and 2 but when I do that, the result is:

```
2018-08-18 2
2018-08-19 1 0.335106
2018-08-20 1 0.335106
```

Thanks for helping.

Now, I have this:

```
if [ $elt_btch | wc -w ] -gt 1 then       
     size_eout_rec=`$last_7th_day $elt_btch  $filesiz`
     awk '{ 
        wrdcnt = (NF - 1)/2
        for (i=1; i<=wrdcnt; i++) 
            print $1, $(i+1), $(i+1+wrdcnt) >> $size_out_arc
          }' <<END
    else if [ $elt_btch | wc -w ] -eq 1 then    
            echo $last_7th_day $elt_btch  $filesiz >> $size_out_arc

         fi
   if
```

Comment: Show us your script.

Comment: This is already in a file. I'm taking tail -30 > this file. Can I just make the enrichment on this file instead of changing the files prior to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General solution:

```
awk '{ 
    half = (NF - 1)/2
    for (i=1; i<=half; i++) 
        print $1, $(i+1), $(i+1+half)
}' <<END
2018-08-18 1 2 0.335106 0.335106
2018-08-19 1 0.335106
2018-08-20 1 0.335106
1970-01-01 1 2 3 4 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4
END
```

```
2018-08-18 1 0.335106
2018-08-18 2 0.335106
2018-08-19 1 0.335106
2018-08-20 1 0.335106
1970-01-01 1 0.1
1970-01-01 2 0.2
1970-01-01 3 0.3
1970-01-01 4 0.4
```

Not sure what you mean by "get rid of the 1's and 2's", but you may want

```
print $1, $(i+1+half)
```

to omit printing the 2nd column

Comment: So I should've said this in my question but the number of columns could vary based on the input data. So on any day, it could become 2018-08-18 1 2  3 0.335106 0.335106 0.335106. Will this still work?

Comment: Yes. I demonstrate that in my test data, which I updated to more closely match your sample data.

Comment: Where is the here doc data? The data appears between `<<END` and a line containing only `END`. There are a few other issues with that code. Paste it into http://shellcheck.net for more detailed help

Comment: If your data is in a file, you should be using `awk '...' filename` with a named file not a heredoc.